# Htaccess replace one image with another one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So Ive been making a code which replaces one image with another without changing the link.

So heres the code that I found on one of the forums.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^.*/fredShip1.png$ /fredShip2.png [L]
</IfModule>
```

So this code not only redirects user to another page but also to a random link.
So original link is **http://toss.rf.gd/storage/fredShip1.png** though it should have replaced the image with **http://toss.rf.gd/storage/fredShip2.png**(Just an example) but it sends the user here **toss.rf.gd/home/vol8_1/[Account info]/htdocs/storage/FredShip2.png**

I added the image too ->
[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6TC9.png)

I am really bad at htaccess so make sure correct me if Im wrong. Also english is not my first language so expect some minor mistakes.

EDIT : So i solved the problem with redirection to a random link. But Im still wondering is it possible to just change the image without changing the link?

Comment: Please clear your browser (and any intermediary) cache. The code you posted does not do what you are describing. That looks like you have previously experimented with a 301 redirect and forgot to include the slash prefix on the _substitution_ string? "So this code not only redirects user to another page but also to a random link." - the code you posted does not do that at all? The code you posted is an _internal rewrite_ only. It rewrites a request for `<something>/fredShip1.png` to `/fredShip2.png` (in the document root).

Comment: Oh, ok I cleared the cache and it solved the problem with random link but the main problem is still here.

Comment: So, what's the "main problem"? Rewriting the request from one image to another? The code you posted already does that, but you need to adjust the file-path to fit your example and the order of directives is important if you have other directives. (Still not sure what you meant by "random link" - that was neither "random", nor a "link"?)

Comment: The main problem is that I need to replace one image with another while the random link one(already solved) was just redirecting the user to /home/vol_8_1/ or something close to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^.*/fredShip1.png$ /fredShip2.png [L]
> ```

The code you've posted already does essentially what you require, except that you need to adjust the paths to match your example. The "problem" with the above rule is that it rewrites the request to `/fredShip2.png` (in the document root), not `/storage/fredShip2.png` as in your example.

Assuming the `.htaccess` file is in the document root of the site and you wish to internally rewrite the request from `/storage/fredShip1.png` to `/storage/fredShip2.png` then you would do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^storage/fredShip1.png$ storage/fredShip2.png [L]
```

There should be no slash prefix on the URL-path in either argument.

If you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file then the order of these directives can be important.

Make sure you've cleared your browser cache before testing.

---

> but it sends the user here `example.com/home/vol8_1/[Account info]/htdocs/storage/FredShip2.png`

That's not possible with the directive you've posted. This is most likely a cached redirect due to an earlier (erroneous) experiment with 301 (permanent) redirects. For example, something like the following would produce the above "erroneous" output:

```
RewriteRule fredShip1\.png$ storage/FredShip2.png [R=302,L]
```

Note the use of the `R` (`redirect`) flag and the lack of a slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string (2nd argument). Since the *substitution* string is "relative", the directory-prefix (ie. `/home/vol8_1/[Account info]/htdocs/` in your example) is prepended to substitution and since this is an external redirect (as denoted by the `R` flag) this then exposes the absolute filesystem path to the user.

NB: The above is a 302 (temporary) redirect - so should not be cached by the browser (at least not by default).